# Customer can not login created by admin

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account, customer-session, core-session

I have installed fresh installtion of magento 1.9.2.2

I have created group in customer group.

If I add any customer to that group using admin panel, and tries to login from frontend in different browser, it shows that

> Invalid login or password.

however if I clicks on forget password, enter user's email, I am getting email with password. Again if I try with same password, not able to login.

Comment: Have you a multi store Website ?

Comment: @prathmeshb1, thanks.. issue has been resolved.

Comment: @KuKu , How you solved that ?

Comment: @Sarfaraj, looks like i am very late to comment, but yes, below is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating customer from Admin panel, `Associate to website` is set as `Admin` by default. In such case, customer cannot login to frontend site. Change it to `"Main website"` or the appropriate website and try again!

Comment: appreciate you big time ... solved.. yesterday i almost wasted 3-4 hours on this.. it was big blocker to go ahead... (bow)

Comment: i did the same but not working...

Answer (score 0):

The website is disabled by default in adminhtml customer view and can't be updated.

You can try using mysql:
Supposing your website_id is 1 and the admin website_id is 0 this code should work, did it for me:

```
update customer_entity set website_id='1' where website_id='0' and email not in (select em from (select email as em from customer_entity where website_id='1') as c)
```